# How can I numerically evaluate the trace of a large matrix to speed up the code?

Tags: matrix, evaluation, parallelization

I have a large matrix (`4Wn*4Wn`) resulted from multiplication of different matrices and I would like to evaluate the trace numerically to speed up the process. Here is the matrix

```
tc = {{0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {-1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, -1, 0, 0}};
m1[x_, y_] = {{0, I Sin[x] + Sin[y], 
    13/4 - Cos[x] - Cos[y], -1}, {-I Sin[x] + Sin[y], 0, -1, 
    13/4 - Cos[x] - Cos[y]}, {13/4 - Cos[x] - Cos[y], -1, 
    0, -I Sin[x] - Sin[y]}, {-1, 13/4 - Cos[x] - Cos[y], 
    I Sin[x] - Sin[y], 0}};
m2[x_, y_, Wn_] := 
  SparseArray[{Band[{1, 1}, {4 Wn, 4 Wn}] -> {m1[x, y]}, 
    Band[{1, 5}, {4 Wn, 4 Wn}] -> {tc}, 
    Band[{5, 1}, {4 Wn, 4 Wn}] -> {ConjugateTranspose[tc]}}];
M[x_, y_] := m2[x, y, Wn]; Wn = 20;
O1[x_, y_] = D[M[x, y], y];
fn[x_, y_, r_] := 
 Block[{ks = M[x, y], 
   id = IdentityMatrix[
     4 Wn]}, {(Inverse[(r - I*0.01)*id - 
      ks]), (Inverse[(r + I*0.01)*id - ks])}]
trace[x_, y_, r_] := 
 Block[{f = fn[x, y, r]}, 
  Re[Tr[-(1/(4 \[Pi])) (1/(
      4 \[Pi]^2)) (O1[x, y].(f[[2]] - f[[1]]).O1[x, 
        y].(f[[2]] - f[[1]]))]]]
```

the target is `Wn=100` but for a test we set it to `Wn=20`to calculate the trace and then I want to  evaluate the sum with respect to `{x,y}`:

```
XT[r_, nc_] := 
 ParallelSum[
  4 ((2 \[Pi])/nc)^2 trace[x, y, r], {x, \[Pi]/nc, \[Pi], (2 \[Pi])/
   nc}, {y, \[Pi]/nc, \[Pi], (2 \[Pi])/nc}]
```

Now, the last step is to evaluate this as a function of `r` and I will use `nc=100` for simplicty (target is `400`)

```
Table[XT[r,100.]//AbsoluteTiming,{r,-2,2,1}]//AbsoluteTiming
{5.39561,{{1.1231,156.671},{1.06852,36.2431},{1.06719,0.275971},{1.06907,36.2431},{1.06769,156.671}}}
```

Then, If I sue `Evaluate` on `XT` to speed it up, it takes few minutes without output

```
Table[Evaluate[XT[r, 100.]], {r, -2, 2, 1}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

Comment: What unit is `Wn`?

Comment: Can you use `AbsoluteTiming` on individual parts of your calculation to try to determine where most of the time is being spent? Because Mathematica caches data and takes time to start up, you may need to restart Mathematica and do a small unrelated calculation and then do measure the time of a particular step. I'm guessing that most of your calculation takes almost zero time and a few key steps take almost all the time. Knowing that can help you and everyone else decide how to focus on the key parts. `ParallelSum` can help or hurt, depending on the structure of the problem you have.

Comment: @ΑλέξανδροςΖεγγ, it is a number and defined above to be 20 in the above example but the target is to be 100

Comment: Highly recommend what Bill has advised. `Total` May also help instead of `ParallelSum`, if that is the one that takes up the most time.

Comment: Matrices with a shape of hundreds by hundreds are not very large.

Comment: @ΑλέξανδροςΖεγγ, that what I believe but the large time it takes makes me say large-:)

Comment: @Bill, my concern is about using `Evaluate ` in the last step, it takes so long and did not work magically as usual?

Comment: I booted MMA, scrape-n-pasted your code, set `Wn=2` without `Parallel` without `Evaluate` and got `{6.78404,{{1.55934,17.2432},{1.31069,7.37015},{1.30124,0.00424746},{1.30446,7.37015},{1.30829,17.2432}}}` I booted MMA, scrape-n-pasted your code, set `Wn=2` without `Parallel` with `Evaluate` and got `{7.10071,{{1.*^-6,17.2432},{1.*^-6,7.37015},{0.,0.00424746},{0.,7.37015},{0.,17.2432}}}` Can you reproduce EXACTLY this? And then bump Wn up a little at a time and try with and without `Parallel` and with and without `Evaluate`? Let's see the numbers.

Comment: @Bill, Without `Parallel` and `Evaluate` I got for `Wn=2`  `{4.86016,{{0.993988,17.2432},{0.961168,7.37015},{0.962931,0.00424746},{0.980407,7.37015},{0.961641,17.2432}}}`. Without `Parallel`and with `Evaluate` I got `{4.86784,{{1.*10^-6,17.2432},{0.,7.37015},{0.,0.00424746},{0.,7.37015},{0.,17.2432}}}`. with `Wn=10`, I got this as above setting ,respectively, `{23.2096, {{4.54728, 80.6235}, {4.71668, 18.675}, {4.83896, 
   0.220973}, {4.516, 18.675}, {4.59063, 80.6235}}}` and `{22.7261,{{0.,80.6235},{1.*10^-6,18.675},{0.,0.220973},{1.*10^-6,18.675},{0.,80.6235}}}`

Comment: @Bill Now with `Parallel` and `Wn=10` 1. without `Evaluate` I got this `{2.1124, {{0.428734, 80.6235}, {0.419949, 18.675}, {0.419845, 0.220973}, {0.419475, 18.675}, {0.424342, 80.6235}}}` and with `Evaluate` I got this `{2.08904, {{0., 80.6235}, {0., 18.675}, {0., 0.220973}, {1.*10^-6, 18.675}, {0., 80.6235}}}`..

Comment: @Bill I noticed something really STRANGE: If I remove `AbsoluteTiming` inside the Table and with `Evaluate` like this `Table[Evaluate[XT[r, 100.]], {r, -2, 2, 1}] // AbsoluteTiming` it runs for minutes without any output, but writing it this way  `Table[Evaluate[XT[r, 100.]] // AbsoluteTiming, {r, -2, 2, 1}] // AbsoluteTiming` gives results as in the previous comment!!!